# price discount after login, and after logged out codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am making a simple cart store, with login session. If a user have logged in, he will get 10% discount for all product. There is no problems here, because the user can get the discount after the user have logged in and i can view the discount, and price after discount.

The problem is when the user have logged out. The manual discount, and price after discount are not show. 
I mean if a product have 20% discount, then when the user logged in the product become 30%, but after the the user logged out, the product off 20% discount disappear, and the price is not a price after 20% discount.

this is code of my view,

```
<?php
if($login == 1) {
    $price_after_discount = $product->product_price - (($product->product_price * (10+$product->product_discount) / 100));
    ?>
    <span style="font-size: 17px;text-decoration: line-through;color: #ccc;"><em>$<?=$product->product_price?></em></span>
    <span style="color: #5169a5;">$<?=$price_after_discount?></span><br>
    <span class="label label-danger" style="padding: .2em .3em .2em;font-size: 70%;border-radius: 0;background-color: #e81f1f;position: absolute;top: 0;right: 0;font-family: roboto;">
      off <?=$product->product_discount+10?>%
    </span>
<?php }else{ ?>
    <span>$<?=$product->product_price?></span>
<?php }?>
```

I know that code is only view of the discount product after logged in, than when he logged out, all the discount will disappear. I don't know how to show the manual discount and count the price after discount when the user have logged out. Please help me how to make it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add your discount calculation in `else` sentence, just without additional 10% discount. Also don't forget to check if base discount exists.
Full code:

```
<?php
if($login == 1) {
    $price_after_discount = $product->product_price - (($product->product_price * (10+$product->product_discount) / 100));
    ?>
    <span style="font-size: 17px;text-decoration: line-through;color: #ccc;"><em>$<?=$product->product_price?></em></span>
    <span style="color: #5169a5;">$<?=$price_after_discount?></span><br>
    <span class="label label-danger" style="padding: .2em .3em .2em;font-size: 70%;border-radius: 0;background-color: #e81f1f;position: absolute;top: 0;right: 0;font-family: roboto;">
        off <?=$product->product_discount+10?>%
    </span>
<?php }if ($login == 0)
    if($product->product_discount != null && $product->product_discount > 10){
    $price_after_discount = $product->product_price - (($product->product_price *$product->product_discount ) / 100);
    ?>
    <span style="font-size: 17px;text-decoration: line-through;color: #ccc;"><em>$<?=$product->product_price?></em></span>
    <span style="color: #5169a5;">$<?=$price_after_discount?></span><br>
    <span class="label label-danger" style="padding: .2em .3em .2em;font-size: 70%;border-radius: 0;background-color: #e81f1f;position: absolute;top: 0;right: 0;font-family: roboto;">
        off <?=$product->product_discount?>%
    </span>
<?php } else{ ?>
    <span>$<?=$product->product_price?></span>
    <?php }?>
```